# matlab plot markers based on third parameter

Tags: matlab, plot, marker

I am plotting data in X-Y, x being time and y being that intensity at that point. However, I was wondering if I could change the type of marker based on a third value?

I am doing the following right now. I'd like to be able to set the marker shape based on a value from 1-6 in zVector, so the marker would be changing throughout the figure.

```
dataAdjusted = dlmread('file.csv');

xVector = dataAdjusted(:,1)
yVector = dataAdjusted(:,2)
zVector = dataAdjusted(:,3)  

figure 
hold on

plot(xVector, yVector, '-ro','MarkerSize',3, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor','k')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example how to accomplish that for `z` values that go from 1 to 3 ...

```
x=rand(1,10);
y=rand(1,10);
z=randi(3,1,10);

plot(x(z==1),y(z==1),'o',...
     x(z==2),y(z==2),'x',...
     x(z==3),y(z==3),'s')
```

I think you can see how it can be generalized using a for loop quite easily.

**Edit**  - here's a for loop implementation:

```
markerlist='sox';
colorlist='rgb';
for n=1:max(z)
plot(x(z==n), y(z==n), markerlist(n),'MarkerSize',5, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor',colorlist(n)) 
hold on
end 
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm having trouble getting this to work with properties. Do you have any insights on this? plot(xShort(z==1),yShort(z==1),'ms','MarkerSize',3, xShort(z==2),yShort(z==2),'kv','MarkerSize',3, xShort(z==3),yShort(z==3),'g+','MarkerSize',3, xShort(z==4),yShort(z==4),'bx','MarkerSize',3, xShort(z==5),yShort(z==5),'ro','MarkerSize',3)